How to average data in past 5 minute intervals?
I wanted to average the data per 5 minutes intervals at column J. But my query doesn't average the data in the past 5 minutes, it's doing the opposite for example:
What I want:



TE-01
TE-02
TE-03
TE-04
TE-05
TE-06
TE-07
timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)
GMT+8 (corrected 5 minutes)




25.1
25.7
24.9
26.2
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:45:52.940



1
0.6
-0.6
0
30.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:47:23.203
07:50:00 AM


25.1
25.7
25
26.3
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:51:05.867



25.1
25.7
25
26.3
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:51:18.927



0.8
0.5
-0.4
0.8
32.2
0
0
2024-06-19 23:52:35.317
07:55:00 AM


25.1
25.7
25
26.3
26
0
0
2024-06-19 23:56:30.233



1.2
0.7
0.2
0.9
31.8
0
0
2024-06-19 23:57:47.440
08:00:00 AM


0.8
0.4
-0.5
0.6
32.5
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:09.667



25.2
25.7
25.1
26.4
26
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:11.447



0.8
0.4
-0.5
0.7
32.6
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:22.670
08:10:00 AM



vs
What I have



TE-01
TE-02
TE-03
TE-04
TE-05
TE-06
TE-07
timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)
GMT+8 (corrected 5 minutes)




25.1
25.7
24.9
26.2
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:45:52.940



1
0.6
-0.6
0
30.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:47:23.203
07:45:00 AM


25.1
25.7
25
26.3
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:51:05.867



25.1
25.7
25
26.3
25.9
0
0
2024-06-19 23:51:18.927



0.8
0.5
-0.4
0.8
32.2
0
0
2024-06-19 23:52:35.317
07:50:00 AM


25.1
25.7
25
26.3
26
0
0
2024-06-19 23:56:30.233



1.2
0.7
0.2
0.9
31.8
0
0
2024-06-19 23:57:47.440
07:55:00 AM


0.8
0.4
-0.5
0.6
32.5
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:09.667



25.2
25.7
25.1
26.4
26
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:11.447



0.8
0.4
-0.5
0.7
32.6
0
0
2024-06-20 00:05:22.670
08:05:00 AM



What's happening is that instead of aggregating the from the past 5 minutes, the query is aggregating the data ahead until it hits the next 5 minute mark. Here's the query responsible for the aggregation of the data in 5 minute intervals. I have included the sample data as well so you can replicate:
-- This is just a sample data from my SO question...
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (
    [TE-01] FLOAT,
    [TE-02] FLOAT,
    [TE-03] FLOAT,
    [TE-04] FLOAT,
    [TE-05] FLOAT,
    [TE-06] FLOAT,
    [TE-07] FLOAT,
    [timestamp] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar ([TE-01], [TE-02], [TE-03], [TE-04], [TE-05], [TE-06], [TE-07], [timestamp])
VALUES
('25.1', '25.7', 24.9, 26.2, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:45:52.940'),
('1', '0.6', -0.6, 0, 30.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:47:23.203'),
('25.1', '25.7', 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:51:05.867'),
('25.1', '25.7', 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:51:18.927'),
('0.8', '0.5', -0.4, 0.8, 32.2, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:52:35.317'),
('25.1', '25.7', 25, 26.3, 26, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:56:30.233'),
('1.2', '0.7', 0.2, 0.9, 31.8, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:57:47.440'),
('0.8', '0.4', -0.5, 0.6, 32.5, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:09.667'),
('25.2', '25.7', 25.1, 26.4, 26, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:11.447'),
('0.8', '0.4', -0.5, 0.7, 32.6, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:22.670');

-- MY QUERY STARTS HERE... IT AGGREGATES DATA AT 5 MINUTE INTERVALS

/*
IGNORE THIS, IT'S JUST NEEDED FOR MY QUERY AND IS NO 
LONGER RELEVANT DUE TO THE SAMPLE DATA
*/
DECLARE @hours INT = 24 

/*
UTC+0 timestamp IS converted TO UTC+08 so it is convinient to look at 
for the users living on that timezone...
*/
DECLARE @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET VARCHAR(10) = '+08:00'
DECLARE @CURRENT_DATE DATETIME = CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE() ,'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET) AS DATETIME)

DECLARE @minutes INT = (@hours * 60)

/*
This is the main select statement, the averaging and aggregation of data at 5 minute 
intervals starts here...
*/
SELECT
    T1 = ROUND(AVG([TE-01]), 1),
    T2 = ROUND(AVG([TE-02]), 1),
    T3 = ROUND(AVG([TE-03]), 1),
    T4 = ROUND(AVG([TE-04]), 1),
    T5 = ROUND(AVG([TE-05]), 1),
    T6 = ROUND(AVG([TE-06]), 1),
    T7 = ROUND(AVG([TE-07]), 1),
    [TS] = dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([timeStamp],'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET)) / 5 * 5, 0)
FROM @MyTableVar
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([timeStamp] ,'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET) AS DATETIME), @CURRENT_DATE) >= 0
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([timeStamp] ,'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET) AS DATETIME), @CURRENT_DATE) <= @minutes
GROUP BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([timeStamp],'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET)) / 5 * 5, 0)
ORDER BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, SWITCHOFFSET(TODATETIMEOFFSET([timeStamp],'+00:00'), @USER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET)) / 5 * 5, 0) ASC

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Also if information is important to the question, include it in the question; don't provide sample data via an off-site resource.

Use decimal and datetime2 if you don't want rounding errors. All those string manipulations are meaningless too, as datetime and datetime2 have no offset. As far as the database knows, the timestamp already is UTC. Use datetimeoffset to remove the ambiguity. If you want to produce results in some other timezone, it's enough to do just use timestamp AT TIME ZONE .... in the SELECT clause.

@PanagiotisKanavos, can you give me example on how can I use datetime2 to fix the grouping?

datetime2 is a type, not a function. datetime has a precision of only 0.003. The types you used will cause rounding errors.   The entire script looks like various answers stitched together, eg dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, is used to round datetime, but you want to group by minutes, not round. You can use DATEPART to extract the various parts of a date like hour and minute, after which `minute/5 returns the interval you want.

Using strings to represent numbers is a bug too. Half the world doesn't use . as the decimal separator. And that's only because China follows the US in this. Where does the data come from ?

@ThomA, I have updated the question to fit the SO policy

@PanagiotisKanavos, our database uses float, some numbers doesn't have a decimal. I fetched this sample data from the database and rounded them to represent 2 decimals only (because it's a requirement, not because I like it that way).
The float data values comes from a temperature sensor.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"our database uses float" That is rarely the correct data type choice. Base-2 and Base-10 number do not mix well when you need to store non-integer numbers. For the above sample data, float is clearly the wrong choice; a decimal(3,2) seems infinitely more approrpriate.

But my concern is the grouping of the data during aggregation on the 5 minute interval. Not the result of the averaging of the numbers. Let us focus on the timestamps.

The GMT+8 (corrected 5 minutes) column on the tables represent how the MSSQL grouped the data on 5 minute intervals. I have updated the question just a while ago.

@jdistro07 what are the expected results? You haven't posted that yet. Aggregations reduce rows while you posted the original data plus a column that doesn't help at all. Should 2024-06-19 23:45:52.940 be displayed as 2024-06-19 23:45:00 or 2024-06-19 23:50:00 ? That's what helps, along with the actual averages you expect.

@PanagiotisKanavos, you can see the table in What I want, that is the expected result. As you can see at the  GMT+8 (corrected 5 minutes) column on that table, I am averaging data past 5 minutes ago. Because the first data is technically past 5 minutes already like 52 seconds ago.

07:45:00 AM has no relation to 2024-06-19 23:47:23.203. What are the expected aggregation results, including the actual timestamps ? There should be just 4 rows. This isn't about past and present, it's about whether you want to display the start or end of the 5 min interval. You already got 2 valid answers that show that. Are the averages wrong? If not, it's just a matter of displaying the start or end.

2024-06-19 23:45:52.940 and 2024-06-19 23:47:23.203 should be averaged to 23:50:00 considering you don't want to offset the time to UTC+08. I just saw that the last 3 data grouping on my What I want section is incorrect. Let me fix it

Done, I fixed What I Want section, also @evilmandarine already gave me the output I need. I'm on the process of testing it on large data right now.

No you haven't. There are 10 original rows instead of 4 result rows with averages and timestamps. In any case, both answers contain any combination you may want. Displaying the start or end of the interval. at UTC, at a specific timezone by name, or by offset. Unless you explain what's wrong with these results, this question will be closed because you still haven't provided the expected results

That's because I removed the mistake. I do apologize if you are disappointed that I made a question that doesn't make sense to you. In any case, thanks for the help regardless.

Panagiotis' aswer is much more complete but since I spent some time trying I'll post this solution here. Focusing only on the grouping this seems to work too:
declare @mindate datetime = (select min(timestamp) from @MyTableVar)

SELECT
    T1 = ROUND(AVG([TE-01]), 1),
    T2 = ROUND(AVG([TE-02]), 1),
    T3 = ROUND(AVG([TE-03]), 1),
    T4 = ROUND(AVG([TE-04]), 1),
    T5 = ROUND(AVG([TE-05]), 1),
    T6 = ROUND(AVG([TE-06]), 1),
    T7 = ROUND(AVG([TE-07]), 1),
    -1 * datediff(minute, timestamp, @mindate)/5 as 'idx',
    dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, timestamp) / 5) * 5 + 5, 0) as 'date group',
    TODATETIMEOFFSET(dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, timestamp) / 5) * 5 + 5, 0) + '08:00:00', '+08:00') as 'date group gmt+8'
FROM @MyTableVar

GROUP BY 
  -1 * datediff(minute, timestamp, @mindate)/5,
  dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute, 0, timestamp) / 5) * 5 + 5, 0)
ORDER BY
  -1 * datediff(minute, timestamp, @mindate)/5

Basically round the timestamp to the next 5min boundary and assign a kind of group id (idx) then group by this id. Retrieve the timestamp and convert to GMT+8. Result is the same as above.
T1     T2   T3      T4      T5      T6  T7  idx date group                  date group gmt+8
13.1 13.2   12.1    13.1    28.4    0   0   0   2024-06-19 23:50:00.000     2024-06-20 07:50:00.000 +08:00
17   17.3   16.5    17.8    28      0   0   1   2024-06-19 23:55:00.000     2024-06-20 07:55:00.000 +08:00
13.2 13.2   12.6    13.6    28.9    0   0   2   2024-06-19 00:00:00.000     2024-06-20 08:00:00.000 +08:00
8.9   8.8   8        9.2    30.4    0   0   4   2024-06-20 00:10:00.000     2024-06-20 08:10:00.000 +08:00


Thanks for posting your solution. But as I have tested. The grouping during the aggregation of this query and @Panagiotis' answer doesn't average past 5 minutes. What it's doing is essentially the same as my script but better. If you look at the first data, the raw timestamp is 2024-06-19 23:45:52.940, it is already ahead the 5 minute cutoff by 52 seconds. which means it should be averaged on the  23:50:00 mark already. Because we are computing past 5 minutes of data

No problem, easiest way is to just add 5min to the query to "round up" to the higher boundary. See edit.

@jdistro07 what you claim isn't correct. Both answers average at 5 minute intervals. Whether you wan to display the start or end of the interval is a matter of adding the interval's duration to the SELECT clause. The itself interval doesn't change

After fixing the types to avoid rounding errors and remove ambiguity, the query can be reduced to this:
;with x as (
    select * ,
    DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(
        datepart(year,timestamp), 
        datepart(month,timestamp),
        datepart(day,timestamp),
        datepart(hour,timestamp),
        5* (datepart(minute,timestamp)/5),
        0,0,0,0,0)
    as TS
from @MyTableVar
)
SELECT
    T1 = ROUND(AVG([TE-01]),1),
    T2 = ROUND(AVG([TE-02]),1),
    T3 = ROUND(AVG([TE-03]),1),
    T4 = ROUND(AVG([TE-04]),1),
    T5 = ROUND(AVG([TE-05]),1),
    T6 = ROUND(AVG([TE-06]),1),
    T7 = ROUND(AVG([TE-07]),1),
    [TS] 
FROM x
WHERE 
    [timestamp] between DATEADD(HOUR,@hours,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) and SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
GROUP BY TS
ORDER BY TS

To display the end of the interval instead of the start, at a specific timezone while taking account of DST rules, we only need to change the TS expression to eg:
   dateadd(MINUTE,5,[TS]) at time zone 'Singapore Standard Time' as TS


float is susceptible to rounding errors and datetime has a precision of roughly 3ms. datetime has no idea of the offset or timezone either. By using datetimeoffset(3) both the rounding errors and ambiguity are solved.
The question is using a common trick to truncate time to an interval. The same thing can be done in SQL Server 2022 using the DATETRUNC function, but neither really helps here.
What's really needed here though is only to truncate to 5 minute intervals. This can be done by extracting the parts of timestamp and using them to create a new value with just the minutes truncated.
Running this script :
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (
    [TE-01] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-02] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-03] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-04] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-05] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-06] numeric(8,1),
    [TE-07] numeric(8,1),
    [timestamp] datetimeoffset(3)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar ([TE-01], [TE-02], [TE-03], [TE-04], [TE-05], [TE-06], [TE-07], [timestamp])
VALUES
(25.1, 25.7, 24.9, 26.2, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:45:52.940'),
(1,    0.6, -0.6, 0, 30.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:47:23.203'),
(25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:51:05.867'),
(25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:51:18.927'),
(0.8,  0.5, -0.4, 0.8, 32.2, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:52:35.317'),
(25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 26, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:56:30.233'),
(1.2,  0.7, 0.2, 0.9, 31.8, 0, 0, '2024-06-19 23:57:47.440'),
(0.8,  0.4, -0.5, 0.6, 32.5, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:09.667'),
(25.2, 25.7, 25.1, 26.4, 26, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:11.447'),
(0.8,  0.4, -0.5, 0.7, 32.6, 0, 0, '2024-06-20 00:05:22.670');


;with x as (
    select * ,
    DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(
        datepart(year,timestamp),
        datepart(month,timestamp),
        datepart(day,timestamp),
        datepart(hour,timestamp),
        5*(datepart(minute,timestamp)/5),
        0,0,0,0,0)
    as ts
from @MyTableVar
)
SELECT
    T1 = ROUND(AVG([TE-01]),1),
    T2 = ROUND(AVG([TE-02]),1),
    T3 = ROUND(AVG([TE-03]),1),
    T4 = ROUND(AVG([TE-04]),1),
    T5 = ROUND(AVG([TE-05]),1),
    T6 = ROUND(AVG([TE-06]),1),
    T7 = ROUND(AVG([TE-07]),1),
    [TS] 
FROM x
WHERE 
    [timestamp] between dateadd(minute,-6000,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) and SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY ts

Produces :
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  TS
13.100000   13.200000   12.200000   13.100000   28.400000   0.000000    0.000000    2024-06-19 23:45:00 +00:00
17.000000   17.300000   16.500000   17.800000   28.000000   0.000000    0.000000    2024-06-19 23:50:00 +00:00
13.200000   13.200000   12.600000   13.600000   28.900000   0.000000    0.000000    2024-06-19 23:55:00 +00:00
8.900000    8.800000    8.000000    9.200000    30.400000   0.000000    0.000000    2024-06-20 00:05:00 +00:00

To get better looking results we can cast to decimal(8,1) instead of rounding:
SELECT
    T1 = cast(AVG([TE-01]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T2 = cast(AVG([TE-02]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T3 = cast(AVG([TE-03]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T4 = cast(AVG([TE-04]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T5 = cast(AVG([TE-05]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T6 = cast(AVG([TE-06]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T7 = cast(AVG([TE-07]) as decimal(8,1)),
    [TS] 
FROM x
...

Returns
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  TS
13.1    13.2    12.2    13.1    28.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-19 23:45:00 +00:00
17.0    17.3    16.5    17.8    28.0    0.0 0.0 2024-06-19 23:50:00 +00:00
13.2    13.2    12.6    13.6    28.9    0.0 0.0 2024-06-19 23:55:00 +00:00
 8.9     8.8     8.0     9.2    30.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 00:05:00 +00:00

Display the interval end
If we want to display the data by the interval's end, all we really have to do is add 5 minutes to TS :
SELECT
    T1 = cast(AVG([TE-01]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T2 = cast(AVG([TE-02]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T3 = cast(AVG([TE-03]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T4 = cast(AVG([TE-04]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T5 = cast(AVG([TE-05]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T6 = cast(AVG([TE-06]) as decimal(8,1)),
    T7 = cast(AVG([TE-07]) as decimal(8,1)),
    DATEADD(MINUTE,5,[TS]) as TS
FROM x

which produces
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  TS
13.1    13.2    12.2    13.1    28.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-19 23:50:00 +00:00
17.0    17.3    16.5    17.8    28.0    0.0 0.0 2024-06-19 23:55:00 +00:00
13.2    13.2    12.6    13.6    28.9    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 00:00:00 +00:00
8.9      8.8     8.0     9.2    30.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 00:10:00 +00:00

Convert to another timezone
Finally, to convert the time to another timezone the safest way is to use AT TIME ZONE with the timezone name instead of the offset. Timezone names aren't affected by DST changes, eg :
SELECT
    ...
    dateadd(MINUTE,5,[TS]) at time zone 'W. Australia Standard Time' as TS
FROM x

Produces
T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  TS
13.1    13.2    12.2    13.1    28.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 07:50:00 +08:00
17.0    17.3    16.5    17.8    28.0    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 07:55:00 +08:00
13.2    13.2    12.6    13.6    28.9    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 08:00:00 +08:00
8.9      8.8     8.0     9.2    30.4    0.0 0.0 2024-06-20 08:10:00 +08:00

Convert by offset
Using SWITCHOFFSET is risky. The correct offset depends on the actual stored date, not the current system date. If the same query runs in December, the offset won't be the same.
If, and only if, we're sure the dates don't cross DST boundaries, we can use
SELECT
    ...
    SWITCHOFFSET(dateadd(MINUTE,5,[TS]),'+08:00') as TS
FROM x


I have taken a look on the result. But it seems like the script you made doesn't consider the seconds. For example the data at 2024-06-19 23:45:52.940 is on the 5 minute mark but it seems on your script its on either  23:45:00 or 23:50:00 that data is already ahead of the 5 minute cutoff 52 seconds already. It should already be averaged at 23:50:00 mark.

Also where did you get the data on the 23:45:00 mark? Because as far as I have manually checked the groupings of the aggregation, the resulting data should start at 23:50:00, not 23:45:00.

@jdistro07 I got the results from your data. You never posted what you actually expect from your query, so there's no way to check what you want. doesn't consider the seconds rounding to 5 minutes eliminates the seconds. should start at 23:50:00, not 23:45:00 then add 5 minutes. It makes no difference. Rounding up is the same as truncating and adding the interval. on either 23:45:00 or 23:50:00 no, there's only one such value and it's on 23:45. The average of 25.1 + 1 is 13.05, 13.1 if you round to 1 digit

Just an alternative solution using milliseconds division:
SELECT  T1 = ROUND(AVG([TE-01]), 1),
    T2 = ROUND(AVG([TE-02]), 1),
    T3 = ROUND(AVG([TE-03]), 1),
    T4 = ROUND(AVG([TE-04]), 1),
    T5 = ROUND(AVG([TE-05]), 1),
    T6 = ROUND(AVG([TE-06]), 1),
    T7 = ROUND(AVG([TE-07]), 1)
,   dateadd(ms,  5 * 60 * 1000 * ceiling(datediff(ms,utc, [timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)] ) / (1000. * 60 * 5)), utc) AS datetimeNew
FROM
(
    VALUES  (25.1, 25.7, 24.9, 26.2, 25.9, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:45:52.940', '')
    ,   (1, 0.6, -0.6, 0, 30.9, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:47:23.203', N'07:50:00 AM')
    ,   (25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:51:05.867', '')
    ,   (25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 25.9, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:51:18.927', '')
    ,   (0.8, 0.5, -0.4, 0.8, 32.2, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:52:35.317', N'07:55:00 AM')
    ,   (25.1, 25.7, 25, 26.3, 26, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:56:30.233', '')
    ,   (1.2, 0.7, 0.2, 0.9, 31.8, 0, 0, N'2024-06-19 23:57:47.440', N'08:00:00 AM')
    ,   (0.8, 0.4, -0.5, 0.6, 32.5, 0, 0, N'2024-06-20 00:05:09.667', '')
    ,   (25.2, 25.7, 25.1, 26.4, 26, 0, 0, N'2024-06-20 00:05:11.447', '')
    ,   (0.8, 0.4, -0.5, 0.7, 32.6, 0, 0, N'2024-06-20 00:05:22.670', N'08:10:00 AM')
) t ([TE-01],[TE-02],[TE-03],[TE-04],[TE-05],[TE-06],[TE-07],[timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)],[GMT+8 (corrected 5 minutes)])
CROSS apply (
        SELECT  cast(cast([timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)] AS date) AS datetime) AS utc
    ) u
GROUP BY dateadd(ms,  5 * 60 * 1000 * ceiling(datediff(ms,utc, [timeStamp (UTC+0 raw timestamp)] ) / (1000. * 60 * 5)), utc)

I take the difference between timestamp date and timestamp datetime in 5 minute intervals, and take the ceiling of it and readd it back to the original timestamp. That will give you the nearest 5 minute interval.
If you want to include exact second time (23:50:00) into the 23:55:00 bracket, you can add 3 ms to the date before doing the calcs.
I didn't include the zoned stuff, but zone date stuff is almost always wrong, so feel free to add it yourself if you really need it.
